# .NET CI server on Linux for building WPF applications

Tags: .net, linux, wpf, continuous-integration

I'm trying to find a solution for CI which can be run on a Linux server that currently holds out SVN repo.

As many of the applications we build are Windows desktop application using WPF as the front end, I'm uncertain if this is possible.

I've seen a number of CI solutions for building ASP application on Linux, and while I realise it's not possible to run a WPF application on linux, is there a CI server which will build WPF applications when not running on Windows?

Comment: To either run or build you would need the same set of dll's (for runtime or compile time) so I think the answer is no. Reason why is because all of the runtime dll's are in GAC which is not available on linux neither is a recent version of .NET libraries. AFAIK you can use `wine` on LINUX to get .NET 1.1.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to get the feeling that this might be the case. If you can post this as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution. Building on Mono isn't an option here, so it looks like CI is out until I can set up a Windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we spoke in comments:

> To either run or build you would need the same set of dll's (for runtime or compile time) so I think the answer is no. Reason why is because all of the runtime dll's are in GAC which is not available on linux neither is a recent version of .NET libraries. AFAIK you can use wine on LINUX to get .NET 1.1